# Приложение на c# не воспроизводит Post/Sendmessage

Tags: c#, sendmessage

Здравствуйте, полностью эмулирую нажатие лкм в программе, повторяю все, что есть в spy++, но программа не реагирует на клик. Программа чистая, там ничего нет, кроме пары кнопок для теста. Код:

```
 PostMessage(handle, WM_MOUSEHOVER, (IntPtr)0, 0);
 SendMessage(handle, WM_SETCURSOR, handle, MakeLParam(18, WM_MOUSEMOVE));
 SendMessage(handle, WM_SETCURSOR, handle, MakeLParam(1,WM_MOUSEMOVE));
 SendMessage(handle, WM_MOUSEACTIVATE, handle, MakeLParam(1, WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
 SendMessage(handle, WM_SETCURSOR, handle, MakeLParam(1, WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
 PostMessage(handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)0x0001, MakeLParam(x, y));
 Thread.Sleep(5);
 PostMessage(handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, MakeLParam(x, y));
```

Spy++ после настоящего клика:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Spy++ после эмулированного клика:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думаю на с++ вы получите то же самое. Используйте `mouse_event` http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread420159.html.

Comment: Не подходит перехват, тк делаю автоматическую панель, на сервере другие работы еще ведутся :(

Comment: А почему одни через PostMessage, другие - через Send. В чем логика выбора? Если нужен именно определенный порядок сообщений, надо все слать одним способом. Система помещает сообщения мыши в очередь, так что наверное все надо через Post.

Comment: Я все способы уже пробовал, если Вы посмотрите на буковки перед смс, то поймете, почему одни через пост, другие через сенд. Замена всех на один тип не даст результата